# Making a HTTP Request with id parameter

Tags: laravel, http

I have 2 projects running in two diffrent ports

In another project I have written this route

Project A

```php
Route::get("/getBook/{id}", function ($id) {
    return response()->json(BlogArticle::find($id));
});
```

This route will be used as an api for other projects to get the needded books.
In the other project i want to retrive the book by sending a id as a parameter {id} in the url
My approach

```php
Route::get("/api/testing", function () {
    $response = Http::get('http://127.0.0.1:900/api/getBook', [
        'id' => 1
    ]);
    
    return $response;
});
```

But nothing is being returned I am getting 404 not found error?

What am I missing?

Comment: You’ll need to append it into the URL. It’s not a named query string parameter. `…/api/getBook/1`

Comment: Thank you @SamiKuhmonen  .  I misunderstood it , now it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the route definition is `Route::get('/getBook/{id}')` it means any `GET` request to that URL will be handled. The `{id}` part is a placeholder in the URL, it does not denote a query string part. Therefore you’ll have to include the ID in the URL itself:

```
$response = Http::get('http://127.0.0.1:900/api/getBook/1')
```

Comment: what about if i want to send some parameters in Http::post how can i do that?